# Re-configure Raspberry Pi as if it was new

Tags: noobs

Was going through a tutorial, and I forgot to enable I2C interface and load the I2C kernal module, as well as a few other things. I just want to get it back to the point as if I didn't configure anything, and I had just pulled it out of the box.

Answer (score 7):

Simply rewrite the SD card with a fresh copy of NOOBS or Raspbian and it will be back to brand new!

Comment: Shouldn't the firmware be downgraded as well (to get the "out-of-the-box" equivalent)?

Comment: The "firmware" is stored as an file on the SD card. It is loaded before the OS loads.

Comment: Ah, ok - thanks. I thought it was flashed somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

No need to flash everything again. Just do `sudo raspi-config` and choose "Advanced settings" there you can enable I2C.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not afraid of losing any saved data, programs etc. then why not just reformat the SD card and load a fresh copy of your preferred OS?